# Change ImageView while button is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

In Android Studio I know it is possible to change the image of a button during its different states with selectors such as

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_pressed" />
</selector>
```

I wanted to know if the same functionality is available with `ImageView`, I have 4 buttons and want to change my `ImageView` to 1 of 4 corresponding images while the button is being pressed. When the user stops pressing the button I want to change the `ImageView` back to its original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could use an onTouchListener

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                //Change image
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //Restore image
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ImageButton to do that. It is a button and it has an image.
You could perhaps use a regular button by setting one of the drawables too. But I think ImageButton is better.

[See ImageButton details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Comment: This wouldn't work since my buttons need to stay transparent, I don't want to change the buttons images, just the background image.